# How do I add a font aswesome's className or id in React

Tags: reactjs

I tried to add an className in fontawesome and give a property(width,padding,fontsize, etc)in the sass but it didn't work what I expected.
Is there any syntax give a className or id in the fa react? It works when I give a div+className and using flexbox but you know this is pretty not a good way if we can use className or id. I will leave my code below!

! 
or

didn't work...

This is my whole main.js file! I will leave my part of my code(my question part)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Main.scss";
import "./Common.scss";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faHeart,
  faComment,
  faPaperPlane,
  faBookmark,
  faEllipsisH,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
// import { FaRegComment } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
// how to impport this faRegComment?
class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div class="main-wrapper">
          <div class="nav">
            <p class="logo"> Westagram </p>
            <input
              class="search-box"
              type="text"
              placeholder="&#xF002; Search"
            />
            {/* ,style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome */}
            <div class="icons">
              <img
                id="compass"
                src="https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/explore.png"
              />
              <img
                id="heart"
                src="https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/heart.png"
              />
              <img
                id="my-page"
                src=" https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/profile.png"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="main">
            <div class="feeds">
              <div class="article">
                <div class="identi">
                  <img class="selfi-identi" src="/images/about.png" />
                  <span class="name"> Jiwan Jeon </span>

                  {/* <i id="test" class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i> */}
                  <div class="faEllipsisH">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEllipsisH}></FontAwesomeIcon>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="pic">
                  <img id="feed-pic" src="/images/ucscPic.png" />
                </div>

                <div class="show-box">
                  <div class="reaction-icons">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart}></FontAwesomeIcon>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faComment}></FontAwesomeIcon>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperPlane}></FontAwesomeIcon>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBookmark}></FontAwesomeIcon>
                  </div>

                  <div class="like-counts">
                    <span>like 4,000</span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="check-comments">
                    <span>
                      UC Santa Cruz will continue to offer most courses remotely
                      or online for spring and summer 2021, providing in-person
                      instruction for a small
                    </span>
                    <a id="space" href="">
                      expanding
                    </a>
                    <br />
                    <a href="">Check the all comments</a>
                    <ul class="feed-comments">
                      <li>test</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="comment">
                  <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
                  <input
                    class="user-input"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Add Comment..."
                  />
                  <button class="post">Post</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="main-right">
            <div class="top">
              <img class="selfi" src="/images/about.png" />
              <div class="main-right-name">
                <span id="eng-name">JiwanJeon94</span>
                <br />
                <span id="kr-name">전지완</span>
              </div>

              <a href="">Transform</a>
            </div>

            <div class="middle">
              <div class="middle-words">
                <span id="recommendation">Suggestions For You</span>
                <a href="" id="view-all">
                  view all
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="recommendation-people">
                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                  <img
                    id="recommendation-people-selfi"
                    src="/images/about.png"
                  />
                  <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                  <a href="">Follow</a>
                </div>
                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                  <img
                    id="recommendation-people-selfi"
                    src="/images/about.png"
                  />
                  <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                  <a href="">Follow</a>
                </div>
                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                  <img
                    id="recommendation-people-selfi"
                    src="/images/about.png"
                  />
                  <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                  <a href="">Follow</a>
                </div>
                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                  <img
                    id="recommendation-people-selfi"
                    src="/images/about.png"
                  />
                  <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                  <a href="">Follow</a>
                </div>
                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                  <img
                    id="recommendation-people-selfi"
                    src="/images/about.png"
                  />
                  <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                  <a href="">Follow</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
              <div class="footer-top">
                <a href="">About</a>
                <a href="">Help</a>
                <a href="">press</a>
                <a href="">API</a>
                <a href="">Jobs</a>
                <a href="">Privacy</a>
                <a href="">Terms</a>
                <a href="">Locations</a>
                <a href="">TopAccounts</a>
                <a href="">Hashtags</a>
                <a href="">Language</a>
                <br />
                <br />
              </div>
              <span>2021 INSTAGRAM FROM FACEBOOK</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

This is my fa icons part

```
                <div class="show-box">
                  <div class="reaction-icons">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart}></FontAwesomeIcon>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faComment}></FontAwesomeIcon>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperPlane}></FontAwesomeIcon>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBookmark}></FontAwesomeIcon>
                  </div>
```

I Will leave sass file just in case

```
@font-face {
  font-family: instagramFont;
  src: url("./westagram.ttf") format("opentype");
}

@mixin icon-size() {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
#root {
  height: 100vh;

  .main-wrapper {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: 100%;

    .nav {
      position: fixed;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-around;
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      border-bottom: solid 1px #dbdbdb;
      z-index: 9999;

      .logo {
        font-family: instagramFont;
        padding-right: 100px;
        font-size: 2rem;
      }
      .search-box {
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: 250px;
        // main css파일이랑 똑같이 세팅 했는데 개발자툴이랑 왜 다른지 -해결-
        height: 28px;
      }
      .icons {
        margin-left: 100px;

        #compass {
          @include icon-size();
          //30*30 으로 세팅했는데 개발자툴에서는 왜 53*53인지
        }
        #heart {
          @include icon-size();
        }
        #my-page {
          @include icon-size();
        }
      }
    }

    .main {
      position: relative;
      top: 70px;
      left: 8px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;

      .feeds {
        position: relative;
        top: 40px;
        right: 5px;
        left: 61px;
        width: 60%;

        .article {
          position: absolute;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          width: 614px;
          height: 954px;
          padding-bottom: 10px;

          .identi {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: flex-start;
            height: 50px;

            .selfi-identi {
              width: 30px;
              height: 30px;
              // padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
              border-radius: 50%;
            }

            .name {
              margin-top: 10px;
              margin-left: 5px;
            }

            #test {
              padding-top: 23px;
              padding-left: 410px;
            }

            .faEllipsisH {
              padding-top: 10px;
              padding-left: 40px;
              // padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
          }
          .pic {
            #feed-pic {
              position: relative;
              padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
              width: 614px;
              height: 614px;
              padding: 5px 0px 2px 0px;
            }
          }
          .show-box {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
            height: 170px;
            padding: 5px 0px 20px 0px;

            .reation-icons {
              #heartShowBox {
                padding-left: 10px;
                font-size: 30px;
                width: 30px;
              }

              .fa-comment-o {
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 5px;
              }
              .fa-send-o {
                padding-left: 10px;
                font-size: 30px;
              }

              .fa-bookmark-o {
                padding-left: 450px;
                font-size: 30px;
              }
            }
            .like-counts {
              margin-top: 10px;
              padding-top: 20px;
            }
            .check-comments {
              .space {
                padding-top: 400px;
              }
            }
          }
          .comment {
            position: relative;
            // margin-top: 75px;x
            .fa-smile-o {
              font-size: 30px;
            }
            .user-input {
              width: 530px;
              height: 20px;
            }
            .post {
              height: 25px;
              border: solid 1px #d3d3d3;
              border-radius: 5px;
              background-color: #b2dffc;
              font-size: 15px;
              cursor: pointer;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    .main-right {
      position: fixed;
      width: 28%;
      height: 98%;
      top: 11.9%;
      right: 4%;
      .top {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        padding-bottom: 3px;

        .selfi {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
        .main-right-name {
          position: relative;
          padding-top: 25px;
          #kr-name {
            opacity: 0.3;
          }
        }
        a {
          margin-left: 40px;
          margin-top: 20px;
        }
      }
      .middle {
        height: 30%;
        padding-bottom: 100px;

        .middle-words {
          padding-bottom: 25px;
          #recommendation {
            margin-left: 23px;
          }
          #view-all {
            margin-left: 70px;
          }
        }

        .recommendation-people {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          #recommendation-section1 {
            #recommendation-people-selfi {
              width: 30px;
              height: 30px;
              margin-top: 13px;
              padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
              border-radius: 50%;
            }
            span {
              position: relative;
              right: 5px;
              top: -18px;
            }
            a {
              position: absolute;
              right: 3px;
              font-size: 14px;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      .footer {
        margin-left: 10px;
        .footer-top {
          .a {
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
            opacity: 0.3;
          }
        }
      }
      span {
        margin-left: 5px;
        opacity: 0.3;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first, replace all `class` with `className`.
`className` work fine with `FontAwesomeIcon`:
`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} className="awesome-custom"></FontAwesomeIcon>;`

Chech this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-frost-bv362?file=/src/App.js